# How to remove an underlying fragment programatically?

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack, fragmenttransaction

The scenario is as follows:

1. "Dashboard Fragment" -> Fragment 1. This transaction is added to back stack. With tag specifed while replacing the fragment as "frag1";
2. Fragment 1 -> Fragment 2. This transaction is also added to back stack. With tag while performing replace operation. The tag is let us say "frag2".

Now in Frgment 2 when the user wants to save data, it will make the web service call. And if it is successful, I want to replace Fragment 2 with NEW Fragment 1.  And if the user presses the cancel button, it will simply perform the back press event and load the Fragment 1.

In the case of successful web service call, replacement is done properly but when I press back button there is still OLDER Fragment 1. It is for obvious reasons.

To get rid of this when the web service call in Fragment 2 is successful, I have written the following code.

```
if (null != getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag1")) {
          getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove
                  (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag1"));
}

loadFragment1();
```

and then I use the call back method to load the Fragment 1 in the same frame layout and replace Fragment 2.

It goes inside of the if block but the older fragment "Fragment1" is still there- UNHARMED.
I am not using any tag in the method addToBackStack() and keeping it like this addToBackStack(null)

I am not able to remove the older Fragment 1. Please let me know what is wrong with this approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
findViewById(R.id.fragment1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: It is giving me NullPointerException. I am using findFragmentByTag().getView().setVisibility(View.GONE) it gives the NPE. I think the reason is, the view is not visible so it gives this exception.

Comment: in my case fragment1 is fragment tag in xml and over it i am adding/replacing new fragment dynamically using java

Comment: You mean FrameLayout id?